# HIQPDF Navigation error on using proxy + https

Tags: vb.net, https, proxy

- .NET 4.5
- HIQPDF 8.0.0.0

I want to create PDFs from webpages using a local proxy.

```
    Dim htmlToPdfConverter = New HtmlToPdf()
    htmlToPdfConverter.SerialNumber = serial
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Compress = True
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.ImagesCompression = 50
    htmlToPdfConverter.Proxy.Host = "192.168.3.200"
    htmlToPdfConverter.Proxy.Port = 3128
    htmlToPdfConverter.Proxy.Protocol = ProxyProtocol.HTTP
    htmlToPdfConverter.MinBrowserHeight = 1080
    htmlToPdfConverter.StopSlowScripts = True


    Dim uri As String = "https://www.google.de"

    Dim bytes As Byte()
    Try
        bytes = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(uri)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

An Exception with message "Navigation error. The proxy host name was not found" occurs, and this seems to be related to https-urls, as any non-https-url I tried has worked, and any https-url not.
The proxy itself works. If I set it locally, I can call https://www.google.de in my Chrome-browser without problems.
So

1. is it even possible to access HTTPS-pages per proxy in HIQPDF?
2. did I made a mistake?